# Initial value problem, ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

Find the solution to the initial value problem

$$y'=(1-11t)y^2,  $$
$$y(0)=-1/9$$

First I separate the variables

$dy/y^2=(1-11t)dt$

Integrate both sides

$-\frac 1y = t-11t^2+c$

$y(t)=-\frac 1{(t-11t^2+c)}$

Using the initial condition, I find c=9

$y(t)=- \frac 1 {(t-11t^2+9)}$

Is this correct? My textbook gives me a different solution

Comment: note that $\int 11t=\frac {11}2t^2+K$